# styling checkbox with css3 doesn't show label in the proper way

Tags: html, css, checkbox

I have the following CSS code:

```
body {
    background: #555;
}



input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}


/* SQUARED THREE */
.squaredThree {
    width: 20px;    
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.squaredThree label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.4);

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d',GradientType=0 );
}

.squaredThree label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredThree label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}

/* SQUARED FOUR */
.squaredFour {
    width: 20px;    
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
}

.squaredFour label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background: #fcfff4;

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead',GradientType=0 );
}

.squaredFour label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid #333;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;

    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.squaredFour label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.squaredFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

and the simple html code:

```
<!-- Squared THREE -->
<div class="squaredThree">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredThree">here is another label</label>
</div>

<!-- Squared FOUR -->
<div class="squaredFour">
    <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredFour" name="check" />
    <label for="squaredFour">here is some label</label>
</div>
```

And as you can see in the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vL416by/) - the result is far from expected, the label is on the box and it's not in one single line.. What can I do to fix it and to show it in a way checkbox-label (single line)?

Comment: checkboxes can't be reliably styled - I suggest you save yourself time and get a jQuery checkbox plugin or something similar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- will need to remove width form the parent `.squaredThree` and `.squaredFour` which is not allowing the text to flow
- `pseudo` element `:before` can be use to add styles for `checkbox` `background` instead on `label`

```css
body {
  background: #555;
}
input[type=checkbox] {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* SQUARED THREE */

.squaredThree {
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.squaredThree label {
  display: inline-block;
}
.squaredThree label:before {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #222 0%, #45484d 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#222', endColorstr='#45484d', GradientType=0);
}
.squaredThree label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #fcfff4;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.squaredThree label:hover::after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.squaredThree input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
/* SQUARED FOUR */

.squaredFour {
  margin: 20px auto;
  position: relative;
}
.squaredFour label:before {
  content: '';
  left: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background: #fcfff4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #fcfff4 0%, #dfe5d7 40%, #b3bead 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fcfff4', endColorstr='#b3bead', GradientType=0);
}
.squaredFour label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.squaredFour label:hover::after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=30);
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.squaredFour input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!-- Squared THREE -->
<div class="squaredThree">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredThree" name="check" />
  <label for="squaredThree">here is another label</label>
</div>
<!-- Squared FOUR -->
<div class="squaredFour">
  <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="squaredFour" name="check" />
  <label for="squaredFour">here is some label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: So actually I have one more question - when I center it with CSS, I got the mismatch of the checkboxes, can you take a very quick look at my jsfiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/rgw4Lvo2/ I don't know what's the case here..

Comment: Just add `.squaredFour { display: inline-block; }` so it doesn't span the whole line as any block would do (tip: use background-color or outline property on each element to see what's going on). Then beware of the next element: it'll go along this element if it isn't block and/or have `width: auto` (other tip: never use `width: 100%`, use `width: auto` except on tables)